# AWS security group add inbound IP rule for dynamic IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

Thanks for taking the time to read this :)

I have a redshift cluster that allows access for a particular VPC security group.
Hence, I have to add an inbound rule when I work on that using my SQL client. But my internet service provider allocates dynamic IP addresses so each time the router is turned on I need to change the inbound rule.

Here is what I can think of to overcome this:

- set a large range on my security group
- using a t2.micro ec2 instance as a jump host ( additional costs involved, so I think option 1 is better for now)

How do I add my service providers' range of IPs as an inbound rule?

Comment: did you tried adding my ip as source of inbound rule?

Comment: I can add my IP , but my IP changes every time my router restarts so I want to add the range of ips 
for ex if my ip is 104.98.14.54 then i want to add 104.98.14.1-254

Comment: On SG you refer to CIDR format, so just add the CIDR of your provider, like `200.100.0.0/16`. It will allow all IPs from 200.100. But open it for a big range like this is not secure. Bastion will allow you to authenticate with SSH, or even with AWS key if you use session manager, which is more secure than SQL authentication.

Comment: why dont you use ec2 instance as spot instance ( which is 70 percent less than on demand instance) and associate elastic IP? cheap I guess :)

Comment: Thank you so much for these suggestions, I'll try them out :)